# Cannot load xdebug module in PHP 8.2 in Windows 11 - incompatible builds

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

I've installed PHP v8.2.12 as a part of an XAMPP installation on my Windows 11.

Used the Xdebug wizard to figure out which binary I needed using the output of `phpinfo();` which returned:

```text
Summary

Xdebug installed: no
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Windows: yes
Compiler: MS VS16
Architecture: x64
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 8.2.12
Zend API nr: 420220829
PHP API nr: 20220829
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
OPcache Loaded: no
Configuration File Path: no value
Configuration File: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Extensions directory: C:\xampp\php\ext

Instructions

Download php_xdebug-3.3.1-8.2-vs16-x86_64.dll
Move the downloaded file to C:\xampp\php\ext, and rename it to php_xdebug.dll
Update C:\xampp\php\php.ini and add the line:
zend_extension = xdebug
Restart the Apache Webserver
```

Did all these things and have attempted to see if it installed correctly using `php --version` which returns:

```text
PHP Warning:  Can't load module 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll' as it's linked with 2.25, but the core is linked with 14.29 in Unknown on line 0
```

After some fair amount of Googling, I think I've figured out that my compilations of PHP and Xdebug are not compatible (see [here](https://sqlite.org/forum/info/a4996456510a5a3a)). The problem is I have no idea how to compile Xdebug from source on Windows (see [GitHub](https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug) docs), nor am I 100% certain this is actually the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: 2.25 is a weird vs version, you may download the dll from the official site again.

Comment: Visit the [official site](https://xdebug.org/download) and choose the one DLL which suits you to download please (I believe for your case it is `PHP 8.2 VS16 (64 bit)`)

Comment: 2.25 is indeed a weird version, and I don't know where it comes from. It should be 14.x or something like that instead. It does seem that the wizard has given you the right file to download. But only if the information that you gave it matches the PHP that you're trying to run. You can't mix the output on the CLI with the output of phpinfo() in the browser in some cases for example.

Comment: Perfect, redownloading via the downloads link instead of the link via the wizard did the trick. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to redownload the dll from the downloads page instead of via the link given to me on the wizard.